# Size of a photo in a cell, inside TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I need to put a concrete size of the photo.
In the imageView.image field

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Quiz Cell", for: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row
        let quiz = model.quizzes[row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = quiz.question
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = quiz.author?.username ?? "Anónimo"
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "none")

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: what's the problem with above code ? set height and width for image in your QUIZ Cell

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: You have to set it in the Quiz Cell, please provide the code for your cell.

Comment: There is no problem in the code. But I need to put a concret size of the image, where i can set those values?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a specific `imageView` size in the `Storyboard` or `.xib` of the cell itself.

You can also set it programmatically if you don't use `Storyboard`'s or `.xib`'s.